# Repeating TestNG or JUnit test suite

Tags: junit, testng

I trying to repeat login_logout.class 10 times. Why can't I repeat this 10 times?

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({login_logout.class})

public class AllTests {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[10][0];
        return Arrays.asList(data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is  "new Object[10][0]" is to construct an two-dimension array:

(1) [10][0] mean the array has 10 lines that each line holds zero object
   ==> Is it supposed to be "[10][1]" ?

(2) As only the code you uploaded, you didn't actually create any real object,
   because the "new Object[10][0]" only make an array not any real object

Comment: I tried Object[][] data = new Object[10][1]; and that didn't help.

Comment: What I mean is like:
 public class AllTests {
        public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){
            Object[][] data = new Object[10][1]; // which u tried
             for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
                 Object[i][1] = new Object(); // create objects
            return Arrays.asList(data);
}

Comment: How is that different from what I had originally?

Comment: Try this:
'code'
public class AllTests{ 
    public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){ Object[][] data = new Object[10][1]; /* which u tried*/ for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) Object[i][1] = new Object(); /* create objects*/ return Arrays.asList(data); } 'code'

Comment: object[i][1]line is giving an error saying object cannot be resolved to a variable public class AllTests{ 
     public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){ 
      Object[][] data = new Object[10][1]; 
      /* which u tried*/ 
      for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        Object[i][1] = new Object(); }
      /* create objects*/ 
      return Arrays.asList(data); 
      } 
    }

Comment: Or we can make it like :   public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 },{ 6, 8 }  
           });
    }

Answer (score 0):

The `Suite` test runner doesn't support parameters. You could rewrite `login_logout` as a parameterized test:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LoginLogoutTest {
  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> values() {
    return Arrays.asList(
        new Object[10][1]);
  }

  public LoginLogoutTest(Object ignored) {
  }

  @Test
  public void doSomething() {
  }
}
```

That being said, I can't think of too many use cases for running the exact same test ten times.